# Can you mine bitcoins or other data a time loop?

Tags: time-travel, time

You have your own time loop. For one day only: at midnight, if you choose, you can transport your mind back 24 hours and relive the day, but with all the memories you have gained. Nobody else will be aware of this. In effect, Groundhog day.

Given this is there a way of generating bitcoins? Given that the bitcoin process simply uses a lot of machine power to get data, could you take the data back in time? So you could loop many times and come out of it after many interations with a heap of bitcoin data.

You could use the loop for other data processing applications - like the SETI task, acting as a single-user cloud processor over a large number of loops. Is there anything you can do which would be valuable, and, crucially which you could carry back in your memory?

NB I'm deliberately avoiding gambling, stock market prediction and other cheating-knowledge-of-the future etc. The idea is to use the loop to get something valuable which is legal and brain-transportable.

Comment: I'm going to have to VTC here, please see the meta post [How to deal with "Please develop my High Concept" questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-please-develop-my-high-concept-questions). This is a fish for plot ideas not a specific answerable question about the world in which your story takes place.

Comment: This is... broad. And opinion based. What metrics are you planning to use to decide which answer is best? Until there’s a bit of work done on narrowing down A: what this time loop is for and b: What you think constitutes a good answer (either of which might give you the answer to your own question) I’m going to agree with Ash and VTC...

Comment: You can go back and kiss Sam Carter!  And hit a golf ball to another planet for good measure!

Comment: Please read our meta post about [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are broad, not objective and you've provided no criteria for judging a best answer, making the question [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  You need to convert your request from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Comment: To be honest, I think this could be turned into a great question on the SciFi stack: What TV shows or movies have used a time loop to achieve something.  Offhand I can think of at least a half dozen.  A search for prior art on the stack exchange dedicated to science fiction might yield a lot of useful content!  (Edge of Tomorrow is an example that might be particularly up your alley)

Comment: @CortAmmon, actually, that's a fantastic idea for all questions of this type.  Get a list of what authors/screen-writers have already done and use that list to narrow your question for here, if it's still necessary.  Dang.  I wish I'd thought of that a year ago.