# How could you carry large amounts of data across time loop iterations?

Tags: time-manipulation, data-storage

A prolific programmer got stuck in a 24h time loop and is trying to code her way out of it, but all her code (and the entire world) gets reset at 6am. What could she do to carry the code she has written (and perhaps data such as trained ML models) over to the next day?

My first thought, which I plan to make a part of the story in any case, is of her trying to compress the data and then memorize the output, but with modern compression technology, she'd still need to memorise at least 1% of the data each day ([based on Hutter Prize results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutter_Prize)), and that's probably infeasible. I of course could have the story focus on her developing a new compression algorithm, but I find that both a bit boring, and perhaps being too close to a [Silicon Valley plotline](https://silicon-valley.fandom.com/wiki/Pied_Piper_(algorithm)).

Other than that, I've thought of various technomagical solutions like firing data into a miniature black hole (a-la Interstellar), but while I'm definitely open to science fiction or even magical realism, I'm looking for something more grounded.

One such grounded idea I had is of her memorising the code by training her muscle memory (possibly the typing movements themselves), like Phil Connors learned to play the piano and to ice sculpt, but I think that would be even less feasible.

Is there some cool way to store data across time that I'm missing? Maybe something in existing fiction?

Thanks

P.S. Note that I found this somewhat similar question "[Can you mine bitcoins or other data a time loop?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/146021/can-you-mine-bitcoins-or-other-data-a-time-loop)" which was voted to be closed, and I understand mine could be closed for the same reason, but here I am, trying anyway; no harm in trying, as everything is going to get reset in a few hours anyway ;)

EDIT:
Thanks @JBH for your comment detailing the suggestion to VTC, and apologies if I misused the platform here, but I didn't know of any better place to post this, and for what it's worth, it really helped, and I appreciate the great answers and comments from everyone. What ended up happening, is that @GrumpyYoungMan, @Goodies, @user and others made me understand that I did indeed have a Worldbuilding issue, but it wasn't really about what I wanted to ask about, but rather, as @Stilez commented about the **what** and the **how** memories gets carried over. And so this deconstruction of my question gave me exactly what I needed, thanks everyone!

Comment: microSD card in the mouth.  Whatever resets time doesn't reset her brain, so keeping a storage device close enough to her brain ought to prevent it from being reset.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan that is also an issue with this question ! It claims, she can solve it by memorizing code. That would involve an electromagnetic field, which apparently does not disappear from her brain. But if the electromagnetic field of the brain is preserved.. why would she not simply switch on the computer at 5:55 AM and store all code she wants to preserve in computer memory ?

Comment: Good point, I haven't thought of this aspect of how the time loop would work, and actually quite like @GrumpyYoungMan's approach, similar to how (some versions of) Superman have him surrounded by an impenetrable but very short-range force field that also protects his suit

Comment: Can we have a list of examples of things that do carry over? I'm assuming for starters, her long term memory and muscle memory do. Anything else at all in the entire universe? However trivial seeming?

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based. This isn't asking about a rule of your world, but about a story consequence or plot development (I should have closed as too story-based...) and as a result, all answers are equally valuable (contrary to [help/dont-ask] rules) and no best answer can be objectively selected. Raw idea generation isn't a good fit for this site. We can help you solve a specific problem (My time rules are A, my solution is B, can you help me flesh out B?) but you're asking us to throw spaghetti at a wall, that's off-topic.

Comment: Thanks @Stilez, that is indeed the question. It seems that the crux of the issue was that I didn't yet do the legwork on this, and just took it for granted, that I'm setting up the same scenario as in films like Groundhog Day. But getting the great feedback here really helped unblock me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They're in the Matrix

I have no idea what explanation you're meaning to give for the time loop, but you could say that it's because she's in a simulation that's resetting/glitching for whatever reason. Being the 1337 haxxor she is, she realizes that there's a problem with caching causing her to remember the previous iterations. She realizes that she feels the exact same between resets, so it's very likely that her body isn't being reset. Thus, she copies her code onto a small USB or other storage device and then swallows it right before the reset happens so it'll be recognized as part of her. To her delight, the device remains inside her the next day, and she, er, extracts it and continues working on it, eventually gaining enough knowledge to reverse-engineer the simulation and get everything back to normal.

What I was originally going to answer:

Right between the resets, the programmer gets a glimpse of a log file. Eventually, she pieces enough of it together to figure out that because of rounding errors, if she stands at certain coordinates, her position won't be reset the next day. Furthermore, since these places aren't being reset, she can place a drive there to keep her information for the next day.

Honestly, though, this is over-complicated and there's too much handwaving and stuff. It's a lot easier to simply swallow a device (I was originally going to go with a paper with the code printed on it before realizing that technology exists).

Comment: Thanks, I see this builds upon @GrumpyYoungMan's comment, and I quite like this direction.

Comment: @yoniLavi Thanks! I was originally going to go in quite a different direction (see the edit), but realized it was needlessly complex.

Answer (score 7):

#### You're neglecting the best compression algorithm known to man.

*The **"I'm a lazy coder in a hurry"(tm)** algorithm beats LZMA2, BZIP2, ZSTD, and many other leading compression algorithms every time. Its high compression ratios will allow your main character to escape the time loop.*

I'm a full time software engineer. And from experience, I can say that a coder writing code of minimum quality, in a hurry, from memory, that they've written a dozen times before, can write a huge amount of code very fast.

Writing code you've written before does come up a lot: I've had many power failures, git repos get corrupted, or I've just misplaced some code and need to redo it. I can also write it faster if I don't care about how readable someone else finds it.

As a concrete example; here's a representative peice of C++ code (it generates all the prime numbers up to 1 million), as written at a professional standard:

```
// C++ program to print all primes
// smaller than or equal to
// n using Sieve of Eratosthenes
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{
    // Create a boolean array
    // "prime[0..n]" and initialize
    // all entries it as true.
    // A value in prime[i] will
    // finally be false if i is
    // Not a prime, else true.
    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
 
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        // If prime[p] is not changed,
        // then it is a prime
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
            // Update all multiples
            // of p greater than or
            // equal to the square of it
            // numbers which are multiple
            // of p and are less than p^2
            // are already been marked.
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
            {
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Print all prime numbers
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
    {
        if (prime[p])
        {
            cout << p << " ";
        }
    }
}
 
// Driver Code
int main()
{
    int n = 1000000;
    cout << "Following are the prime numbers smaller "
         << " than or equal to " << n << endl;
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)

That's 50 lines of code, of a standard I'd be happy submitting professionally to my companies code base. That'd take me an hour or so to write to that standard, as I'd probably go back over it and iteratively improve and refactor it to get it to that standard.

It's also 1349 bytes. And the best compression I've seen on C++ code like this (best case - like when it gets into the millions of lines) is about 10 to 1 (using extreme settings in lzma2 or bzip2), so this would require 134 numbers between 0 and 255, since you don't have a 256-key keyboard. If done in hexadecimal, it'd be 268 keystrokes to enter the code, if you can type at 60wpm, (15,000 keystrokes per hour), you should be able to knock this out in 64 seconds.

Scaling that up, you can write 180,900 bytes in 24 hours. That'd decompress to 1.8mb, which is about 60,000 lines of code.

However when we apply the "I'm a coder in a rush"(tm) compression algorithm (at best compression level) to that code, we get:

```
n=2;main(m){n<1e6&&main(m<2?printf("%d\n",n),n:n%m?m-1:n++);}
```

([source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5818))

That's 60 bytes. It's also 60 typable characters - 60 keystrokes. That's 4.5 times fewer keystrokes than the compressed C++ entered in binary hexadecimal.

I tried typing that line out over and over. First time took nearly a minute, but by about attempt number 5 I could do it in 18 seconds. At 60wpm, you're looking at 14.4 seconds to type that, which I could probably hit with practice. That's 50 "lines of code equivalent" in 14.4 seconds.

Extrapolating from that, you'll be able to type 300,000 "lines of code equivalent" in a 24 hours. That's a lot of code.

[image]

[Graph source](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/07/google-runs-on-5000-times-more-code-than-the-original-space-shuttle). So you can build an early Unix kernel, or a half-dozen Iphone apps, or most of the space shuttle. But not quite the full Windows 3.1 experience.

Going off the [estimation's for cost of the linux kernel on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code), which estimates 3,750 lines of code is 1 man-year worth of professional output, you'll be able to write the equivalent to 80 man-years worth of work in a 24 hour period. That's gotta be enough work to escape a timeloop.

Another advantage to writing low-quality code instead of compressing code is that you can change small parts of it without having to rememorize huge chunks.

Comment: She could also be a [code golfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) :P

Comment: Thanks, I like and upvoted your suggestion, but I will say that it skirts the actual question. And she would still need to memorize an inordinate amount of minified code. I would very much prefer to have the crux of the plot actually deal with overcoming the time-loop reset and finding a way to move data across it.

Answer (score 3):

**Recruit J squad.**

She cannot do it alone.  She can't finish the code.  Even though she finally knows it all by heart the day is not long enough for her to enter and run it.

She needs help.  She finds out who can help her.  She recruits him, and then her, and then him too.  Each day she recruits them again.  They write the code with her.  Each one makes the same mistakes each time, except when they don't because she sees it coming.  They improve it each time.  It is better than it was.

She does not code.  She coaches.  And with her leading them the three of them finally finish it in the day.

--
This aspect is where Edge of Tomorrow diverged from Groundhog Day and what really made it a fine film.

Comment: Ooh, I love this direction, thanks!

Comment: Brooks' Law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law applies here.   I have enough years of experience onboarding and being onboarded to new engineering projects to say that it's implausible to get up to speed that fast for anything larger than "Hello, world!".

Comment: Only the person who retains memories will improve. All others will show no improvement at all since they do not retain experience: Whatever bad habits or thinking patterns the helpers have will persist. Thus, the programmer who is stuck in the time loop has to memorise the 'correct' code and reproduce it after each reset. Therefore, the problem of retaining information is still there, helpers or not.

Comment: @Otkin, even if you as the nonlooper have no memory of doing what I am asking you to do, I do.  I remember _you_.  And you are gifted but you are not easy to coach.  I remember the fuss you put up and how stubborn you get about your quirks.   I know about that team you were on in 9th grade because when you think of them you quit fussing.   I know the kind of code you want to write and now I encourage you to write it.  I know you on that day really, really well.   And on that day for that project I become the best coach you have ever had and that you ever will have..

Comment: @Willk Breaking habits requires time which measures in days and months, not hours. One can be a brilliant coach but unless they have some divine powers they will not be able to change a person on a fundamental level in a matter of minutes. It also makes no sense to start each loop from 0 if it is possible to have at least partially completed code. The only exception is a situation when the code itself is short but you need to test a multitude of different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

## The Global Human Harddrive

Due to the completely perfect nature of the reset, she quite quickly comes to the conclusion that data cannot be stored from her past. However, she notices that data can actually be stored in the form of **other people's future.**

Just like in the groundhog day movie, other humans in the world will reliably repeat the same thing every single reset. This provides a nice little opportunity to store some information without needing to remember much - specifically, the only thing required to remember is the correct sequence of actions to activate someone else. Essentially, the goal of the human harddrive is to provide just the right bit of influence to get multiple other humans to reliably repeat the data for us. At its simplest, this could be crowdsourcing the code online - all she needs to remember is the people to ask, or a program which performs the asking for her. More advanced forms of the human harddrive could involve using existing project management AI which in turn triggers a collaboration of hundreds of people, or influencing the right people who in turn get a team on what's needed.